# Why does kernel-devel contain so many "empty" directories?

Tags: compiling, linux-kernel, package-management, kernel-modules

I have been a Windows kernel developer for many years. Now I start to develop Linux kernel modules.

To begin with, I installed `kernel-devel` under `/usr/src/kernels/$(uname -r)`. However, after checking the installation folder, I am confused because there seem a lot of seemingly useless folders and files inside the directory. Many folders are empty except for two files: `Kconfig` and `Makefile`.

Under Windows, to develop kernel device drivers, I just need an include folder containing all necessary header files, and an lib folder containing necessary libraries to link.

Under Linux, I can't understand why there are so many seemingly useless folders.

Any explanations?

Comment: either put your headers under `/usr/local/src`, or install your distro's package. it will probably be called `linux-headers` or somesuch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `kernel-devel` package in Fedora and other Red Hat derivatives [does not contain the full kernel source](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/I_need_the_Kernel_Source), just headers for public interfaces and makefiles needed for driver development. Most headers can be found under `/usr/src/kernels/$(uname -r)/include/` and some architecture specific headers, e.g. for x86 under `/usr/src/kernels/$(uname -r)/arch/x86/include/`.

The directories with `Kconfig` and `Makefile` are not useless, you only don't see the complete picture because you don't have the entire kernel source (which you typically wouldn't need for driver development anyway).